# Python: Creating AreaChart3D in a recursive way

Tags: python, excel, graph, 3d, openpyxl

My target is to create some AreaChart3D plots in an automatically way.
Precisely, for example I have the following picture:

[image]

This table is automatically outputed by a tool.
I can have only one graph, maybe 2 graphs or even 100 graphs (does not matter so much), it is important every time I will have this kind of behavior with *Location*, *Speed*, and some *times* inside.

Now, I would like to have in the second sheet(ws2_obj) 4 graphs or maybe 2 graphs depends how many graphs will be outputed by the tool.

If I would have had a fixed number of graph it would have been easier.
Because this graphs are not fixed i have to cover the entire sheet and I do not know how to do it.
Also, there is another question: how to handle **Depth (% of base)** using Python?

```
from openpyxl.chart import (
    AreaChart3D,
    Reference,
)
wb_obj = xl.load_workbook('Plots.xlsx')
ws_obj = wb_obj.active
ws2_obj = wb_obj.create_sheet("Graphs")
c1 = AreaChart3D()
c1.legend = None
c1.style = 15    
cats = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=1, min_row=7, max_row=200)
data = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=2, min_row=6, max_col=8, max_row=200)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
c1.set_categories(cats)
ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, "A1")
wb_obj.save("Plots.xlsx")
```

The Code above produces only one graph, but how should I proceed to create 2 or 4 or 100 graphs?

**Later edit 1:**

I tried something like this and it is almost working:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    c1 = AreaChart3D()
    cats = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=1, min_row=7, max_row=200)
    data = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=2, min_row=6, max_col=i * int(step), max_row=200)
    c1.title = ws_obj.cell(row=1, column=i * int(step)).value
    c1.legend = None
    c1.style = 15
    c1.y_axis.title = 'Fire Time'
    c1.x_axis.title = 'Temperature'
    c1.z_axis.title = "Velocity"
    c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    c1.set_categories(cats)
    ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, "A2")
```

For me the last `ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, "A2")` seems to be the problematic one.

Instead of `A2` I would like to use something like `ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, cell(row=2, column=i)).value` but does not working.

**Later Edit 2**
I have observed if you want to add a chart to a certain cell, you have to use something like: `ws2_obj.add_chart(my_chart, "R2")`

In order to use the `for` loop I tried to find out a way to get this value **R2**.
Please, see below:

```
my_cells = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    my_cell = ws2_obj.cell(row=1, column=i * int(step) - (int(step) - 1))
    my_cells.append(my_cell)
print("My_Cell:", my_cells)
new_cells = []
for i in my_cells:
    new_cells.append(re.findall("\W\w\d", str(i)))
new_new_cells = []
for i in new_cells:
    new_new_cells.append(i[0])
print("new_new_cells:", new_new_cells)
final_list = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', _) for _ in new_new_cells]
print("final list:", final_list)
```

And the output will be `['A1', 'H1', 'O1']`

and then I can output the graph:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    c1 = AreaChart3D()
    # my_cell = ws2_obj.cell(row=i, column=i * int(step))
    cats = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=1, min_row=7, max_row=255)
    data = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=2, min_row=6, max_col=i * int(step), max_row=255)
    c1.title = ws_obj.cell(row=1, column=i * int(step)).value
    c1.legend = None
    c1.style = 20
    c1.y_axis.title = 'Time'
    c1.x_axis.title = 'Location'
    c1.z_axis.title = "Velocity"
    c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    c1.set_categories(cats)
    c1.x_axis.scaling.max = 75
    c1.y_axis.scaling.max = 50
    c1.z_axis.scaling.max = 25
    ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, str(final_list[i - 1]))
```

Comment: I'd have to check the module's code to see how flexible the position coordinates can be but as you can see from my example you can create the coords as a string from variables. 
To better help achieve your chart placement, what is your preferred placement pattern? 
Do you just want to place all charts across the 1 row until there is no space? That would allow for about 1638 charts based on the default size. Or would you prefer to have 10, 15, 20 or more/less per row down the sheet?

Comment: I've added some addtional information including example code on generating the chart anchor position for 1) all charts on the one row and 2) charts placed in a pattern of X charts per row down the sheet.

Comment: @moken thank you for your response. I managed to do it somehow in my own way. I will update the question. I still have a question regarding the plotting. How Depth (% of base), X rotation, etc. could be modified?

Comment: If you have question about plotting or anything not directly related to this charting/layout query you should **create a new question** and not add to this one.

Comment: @moken I am thinking is related to this question, because I have to give a shape to these graphs in order to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of the series data (position where the data series starts). The list has 1 element per series. Iterate the list creating a chart for each and ensure you have some means to place the chart in a unique position.
Example code with comments below.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import (
    AreaChart3D,
    Reference,
)


def create_chart(tl, maxr, hdr, x_ax):
    """
    Creates a standard Area 3D Chart
    """
    cht = AreaChart3D()
    cht.legend = None
    cht.style = 15

    cht.title = hdr + " Chart"
    cht.x_axis.title = x_ax
    cht.y_axis.title = 'Something'  # Some text for the y axis

    data = Reference(ws_obj, min_col=tl[0], min_row=tl[1], max_col=tl[0]+1, max_row=maxr-1)
    cht.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

    return cht


## Sheet constants
chart_header = 'Speed'  # It is assumed this is located in a merged cell
x_axis_header = 'Location'
series_topleft_header = 25

## Load Workbook and Sheet of Excel with data series
wb_obj = xl.load_workbook('Plots.xlsx')
ws_obj = wb_obj.active

## Get the total used rows in the sheet (end of the series table)
maxrows = ws_obj.max_row

speed_row = ''
speed_col_start = ''
speed_col_end = ''
speed_col_letter = ''

## Get a list of Merged cell in the sheet these contain the Headers for position referencing
merge_list = [m.coord for m in ws_obj.merged_cells.ranges]

## Search for the row with Header name 'Speed' to use as reference for series data postioning
for merge_element in ws_obj.merged_cells:
    merge_cell_val = merge_element.start_cell.internal_value
    if merge_cell_val.lower() == chart_header.lower():
        speed_row = merge_element.max_row
        speed_col_start = merge_element.min_col
        speed_col_end = merge_element.max_col
        speed_col_letter = merge_element.start_cell.column_letter

series_header_row = speed_row + 1
series1_start = speed_col_letter + str(series_header_row+1)

"""
Obtain the location of the top left cell where the series data exists
This searches the row below the header (containing the text 'Speed') for the first
series header (i.e. 25 in the example) and adds each position to the series_postion_list
"""
series_position_list = []
for row in ws_obj.iter_rows(min_row=series_header_row,
                              max_row=series_header_row,
                              min_col=speed_col_start,
                              max_col=speed_col_end):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == series_topleft_header:
            series_position_list.append([cell.column, series_header_row])

## Create the Charts
""" 
With the series_position_list indicating the top left cell of the series data
and the number of rows in the series determined be the maxrows - 1. This data
can be passed to the create_chart function to create the chart.

Charts are placed below the series data table from Column A with two charts
per row. First row for chart location is 2 rows below the series table.
"""
chart_start_row = maxrows + 2
chart_col = 'A'

"""




The series_position_list is used to create 1 chart per series
The chart creation function takes the top left coordinate and max rows along
with Chart header name and x axis header name
"""
for enum, top_left in enumerate(series_position_list, 1):
    chart_obj = create_chart(top_left,
                             maxrows,
                             chart_header + ' ' + str(enum),
                             x_axis_header)

    ## This sets the position the chart will be placed. Based on standard size
    ## of plot area the charts are 16 rows and 10 columns apart
    if enum == 1:
        pass
    elif enum % 2 == 1:
        chart_col = 'A'
        chart_start_row += 16
    else:
        chart_col = 'J'

    ## Adds chart to the Excel sheet
    print(f"Adding chart {chart_header + ' ' + str(enum)} to Excel:")
    print(f"Series Data Start; Row:{str(top_left[1]+1)} Column:{top_left[0]}")
    ws_obj.add_chart(chart_obj, chart_col + str(chart_start_row))

    print("--------------\n")

wb_obj.save("Plots.xlsx")
```

[image: Output for example data provided]

-----------------Additional Information--------------
**add_chart** is a method that accepts two arguments; the chart object and optionally an anchor point (i.e the top left cell where the chart is placed in the sheet). Use of .value at the end of

```
ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, cell(row=2, column=i)).value
```

is invalid as you are not entering the method into the cell you are using the method to add the chart object c1 at position **cell(row=2, column=i)**. Using **cell(row=2, column=i)** is also an invalid syntax. You may have meant to use **ws2_obj.cell(row=2, column=i)** as the anchor. This would be accepted by the add_chart method however when saving the worksheet there would be an error on checking the anchor point as this expects the anchor to be an "Excel style coordinate" i.e. a string like **'A2'** rather than a cell object like **ws2_obj.cell(row=2, column=i)**. Even using **(2, 1)** would fail the same check.
To set the anchor points I will show how to do two options; All charts on the same row and X charts across the row then start next X charts on the next row etc.
**Place all charts on same row;**
If you are going to put all charts on the same row then the row coord will not change and only the column position needs adjustment for each chart.
You can generate the anchor points like below, the example code uses a for loop with 18 elements;

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_to_tuple
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

anchor = 'A2'         # Position of anchor, first anchor point is 'A2'
column_separation = 9 # Number of columns to separate each chart
for i in range(0, 18):

    coord_tuple = coordinate_to_tuple(anchor)
    row = coord_tuple[0]

    col_offset = column_separation if i > 0 else 0

    col_new = get_column_letter(coord_tuple[1] + col_offset)

    anchor = f'{col_new}{row}'
    print(f'Adding chart at Anchor point {anchor}')
    ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, anchor)
```

This will put the chart at the following achor points;
A2, J2, S2, AB2, AK2, AT2, BC2, BL2, BU2, CD2, CM2, CV2, DE2, DN2, DW2, EF2, EX2, EO2

**Placing the charts is a pattern.**
Placing the charts is a pattern of rows and columns is similar to the previous code however when the number of charts reaches your limit the 'row' value has to change and the column resets back to 'A'.
The example code again uses a for loop with 18 elements and splits the charts into rows of **max_chart_row**, set to 5 in this case;

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_to_tuple
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

anchor = 'A2'
column_separation = 9
max_chart_row = 5
for i in range(0, 18):

    coord_tuple = coordinate_to_tuple(anchor)
    row = coord_tuple[0]

    col_offset = column_separation if i > 0 else 0
    
    # When the number of charts across the row is reached, set the  row to 16 more than the current
    # and reset the column offset to 0
    if i % (max_chart_row) == 0 and i != 0:
        row = row + 16
        col_offset = 0
        col_new = get_column_letter(col_offset+1)
    else:
        col_new = get_column_letter(coord_tuple[1] + col_offset)

    anchor = f'{col_new}{row}'
    print(f'Adding chart at Anchor point {anchor}')
    ws2_obj.add_chart(c1, anchor)
```

This will put the chart at the following achor points;
A2, J2, S2, AB2, AK2,
A18, J18, S18, AB18, AK18,
A34, J34, S34, AB34, AK34,
A50, J50, S50

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) it is indeed useful. I am still trying to create my own solution.  I managed to do something, but not at all. 
Precisely, I can create 3 or 4 or 100 graphs, but all the graphs are place one over the other in the same place. I do not know how to set up the "add chart". 

Please, see my last edit.